# CSS autoheight, but fit content to height of div

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contains three child-div. The left and the middle div have:

```
float: left
```

while the right one has:

```
float: right
```

Because this would destroy my layout really bad, I have used the clearfix-hack:

```
.cf { zoom: 1; }
.cf:before,
.cf:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.cf:after { clear: both; }
```

This works so far, but I want the right div to be an indicator. So it's height should fill 100% of the parent div.

How could i accomplish that?

P.S.Here is the full code:

```
<div id="mobile_table_background" ng-show="showTable==true">
<div id="mobile_ergHeader">
{{responseData.length}} Suchergebnisse
</div>
<div class="cf" ng-class="{ 'evenbackground': $even, 'oddbackground': $odd}" ng-repeat="data in responseData  | limitTo:limit">
    <div class="mobile_imgClass"><img class="table_img" src="img/noten.png" /></div>
    <div class="mobile_content">
        <h5>{{data.titel}}</h5>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Komponist: </th>
                <td>{{data.komponist}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Instrumente: </th>
                <td>{{data.instrumente}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Schlagworte: </th>
                <td>{{data.schlagworte}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Verlagsjahr: </th>
                <td>{{data.verlagsjahr}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="status" ng-class="{ 'm_available': data.status=='entlehnbar', 'm_taken': data.status!='entlehnbar'}"></div>
</div>
<div class="imgClass">
    <img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" ng-if="loading==true">
    <span ng-if="noResults==true">Keine Ergebnisse gefunden!</span>
    <a href="" ng-click="loadMore()" id="loadmoreButton" ng-if="loadMoreButton==true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>Lade mehr<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: cant you give `height:100%` for the right div??

Comment: sorry but this isn't a full working code sample, it seems like its missing CSS. it would be far easier to examine your problem with a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: okay I'll make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```css
.container {
    background-color:lightgray;
    height:300px;
}
.section {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 32%;
}
.right {
    height:100%;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left section">Left</div>
    <div class="middle section">Middle</div>
    <div class="right section">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In essence, you could apply any method intended to have equal height columns. Several methods are outlined here: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Try setting:

```
#mobile_table_background {display: table}
#mobile_ergHeader, .cf, .imgClass {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Using table-cell will make all containers the same height (not just the last one), but if that's an issue, check the other methods in the link above.